# Selected value not showing when selecting from mat-select element with two radio groups inside

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a dropdown that has two radio groups inside. It would look something like this:

```
Sort By:   
  Option 1
  Option 2
  Option 3

Order:
  Ascending
  Descending
```

Image of the dropdown:

[image]

Left: image of what I'm trying to achieve Right: what happens when I make a selection (placeholder value remains):

[image]

I have the styling the way I want it but I'm running into an issue where when I make a selection, the dropdown does not populate with the selected value. I would want to show the value in the 'Sort By:' radio group.

**sample.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="c-table-header__sort" (click)="sort()">
  <mat-select class="c-table-header__sort-select" placeholder="Sort">
    <mat-option class="c-table-header__sort-select-option">
      <div>Sort by</div>
      <mat-radio-group class="c-table-header__sort-select-option-rgroup__sort" #sortOptionGroup [(ngModel)]="radioData">
        <mat-radio-button name="order" class="c-table-header__sort-select-option-rgroup__sort-rbutt"
          *ngFor="let sort of sortOptions.options" [value]="sort">{{sort}}
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
      <div>Order</div>
      <mat-radio-group class="c-table-header__sort-select-option-rgroup__order" #sortOrderGroup [(ngModel)]="radioTwoData">
        <mat-radio-button name="sort" class="c-table-header__sort-select-option-rgroup__order-rbutt"
          *ngFor="let sort of sortOptions.order" [value]="sort">{{sort}}
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**sample.component.ts** (relevant parts)

```
Component({
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class BillPayScheduledDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

...

radioData;
radioTwoData; 

...   

    sort() { 
        console.log(this.radioData);
        console.log(this.radioTwoData);
    }

}
```

**sample.component.css** (relevant parts)

```
.c-table-header__sort-select-option{
    min-width: 75px;
    min-height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.c-table-header__sort-select-option-rgroup__sort,
.c-table-header__sort-select-option-rgroup__order{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

As I'm writing this, I'm also wondering if putting this all in a form would be possible/easier. Appreciate any insights/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `placeholder` value of your `mat-select` to the currently selected radio button value you can do it like this.

In your component:

```
radioData = '';
radioTwoData = ''; 

getPlaceholder(): string {
  if (!this.radioData && !this.radioTwoData) {
    return 'Sort';
  } else {
    return this.radioData + ' ' + this.radioTwoData;
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<mat-select class="c-table-header__sort-select" [placeholder]="getPlaceholder()">
```

This will show the selected option(s) as the placeholder in your `mat-select`. If you want to display the selected values in the select element below the `placeholder` then you need to use the `[value]` binding of the `mat-options`, but as it seems from your question that is not what you want.

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-gddsrp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   is a stackblitz of it all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The value is actually what I want! I tried accessing the value property of the mat-option in my component: '@ViewChild('sortMatOption') sortMatOption: ElementRef;' and then setting it using 'this.sortMatOption.nativeElement.value = this.radioData;' but that doesn't seem to work. Is this the right approach?

Comment: I've also tried binding [value] of the mat-option to radioData but that didn't seem to work either

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz, have a look at it. Currently only one of the radio button groups is displayed as the value, do you need both to be displayed?

Comment: Hm I'm a little bit confused. Did you mean 'let option of sortOptions[0].options' instead of 'let option of optionGroup.options' in the inner ngFor? Also, could you explain why you used a ng-container as well as why you put the mat-option inside the radio group as opposed to outside?

And yes, if you could include both the radio button groups and their values, that'd be appreciated.

Comment: The `ngFor`s should be ok like this, I restructured the data model a bit, have a look at it. The `ng-container` is a structural directive, I use it here to wrap the `div` and the radio button groups, as we are iterating over them, e.g. creating multiple `div`s and radio button groups. If you wrap the complete radio group in a `mat-option` then the complete group is one option, but I think it would be better if each radio button is one option.